# Compile/Link with absolute path

Tags: c, macos, gcc, linker, ld

How to avoid "Unsafe use of relative rpath ... with restricted binary" on OS X El Capitan ?

Is there a flag to compile & link my library so that it uses absolute path of another library ?

There is a solution with CMAKE and a solution using `install_name_tool` but I can't find one to compile/link with `ld` or (`gcc -Wl,...`) ?

Comment: What do you mean by _'general linker tool'_?

Comment: for example using gcc.. -Wl,..

Comment: Actually, the _general linker tool_ for macOS and many Unix systems is `ld`. From `man ld`: _'The `ld` command combines several object files and libraries, resolves references, and produces an ouput file.'_. Yes, there's a typo in the word 'ouTput'.

Comment: I'm fine with that, edit the question